# Dashing - reorder/sorting widgets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, dashing

is it possible to reorder/move widgets by given property on the dashboard ?

i am adding widgets dynamically to the dashboard by pushing data from a job to the erb file:

```
<div class="gridster">
  <ul>
   <% settings.servers.each do |data| %>
       <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
         <div data-id="<%=data['webHost']%>" data-title="<%=data['name']%>" data-version="<%=data['Version']%>"  >
      </li>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: does it meter?  let's say sample.erb

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your widgets changing `data-row` and `data-col`.

If there are some property on your `data` that can be used to sort them the widgets, you could use it on `data-row` and `data-col`

Ex.:

```
<% settings.servers.each do |data| %>
   <li data-row="<%= data['row'] %>" data-col="<%= data['col'] %>" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
     <div data-id="<%=data['webHost']%>" data-title="<%=data['name']%>" data-version="<%=data['Version']%>"  >
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried to order it by row and col - it's seem that the widgets are override each other. (if this erb build 400 dynamically widgets , after using row and col i will end up with only one widget at x=1 y=1 location).

Comment: how would you order this set of widget by version for example ?